# Android Acitivity Life Cycle Handling error

Tags: android, sqlite, qr-code, android-lifecycle

Good Day, So I have this program where the user will scan a QR code and get the value of it in the SQLite database but before I get the value the dialog box pops-up messaging me that "there is no participant found". Below is my code:

This is my onStart override.

```
     @Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    getparticipantid = tvParticipantID.getText().toString();
    etparticipantidvalue.setText(getparticipantid);
    getParticipantIbeam();
}
```

This is my activity where it will load the data from the database once the user scans the QR code.

```
    private void getParticipantIbeam()
{
    SQLiteFunctionUlitity.GameIBeamParticipant memberInfo = SQLiteFunctionUlitity.getparticipantIbeam(getparticipantid, mDbHelper.getSqliteObjectWithReadable());
    if (memberInfo != null)
    {
        tvParticipantName.setText(memberInfo.getParticipantName());
        tvParticipantNation.setText(memberInfo.getParticipant_nationality());
        tvParticipantCategory.setText(memberInfo.getCategory());

        tvWave.setText(memberInfo.getWave_number());
        tvCategory.setText(memberInfo.getCategory());
    }
    else
    {
        Context context = this;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder1.setMessage("No Participant found in the Game.");
        builder1.setCancelable(true);

        builder1.setPositiveButton("Scan Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(GameiBeamLineTracing.this, ScanGameIbeam.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder1.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                onStop();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
        alert11.show();
    }
}
```

As you can see I call the getParticipantIbeam activity in onStart method but when  I call it, it reads the else statement rather than the if statement.

I know this is a simple if else statement and lifecycle but I am desperate to know the answer.

Comment: This is beacause your "memberInfo" is giving null.

Comment: Yes I know, but how can I check if it is null by not showing first the dialog box stating that there is no participant found? Because I call the activity in the onStart.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the library for scanning QR code, its very simple it may help you.

[QR Code implementation library for android, Click here (blikoon)](https://github.com/blikoon/QRCodeScanner)

Definitely this library will solve your all QR Code related issue and dont forget to implement run time permissions like photo , gallery etc.